# Need help solving Java recursive

Tags: java, recursion

I been trying to figure out how to solve this question but I do not understand. If i take `mystery(2,25)`, `b` is not `==0` and `b%2=1` so then I have `mystery(2+2, 25/2) + 2`. I dont understand what I do with the `+2` in the end and I dont understand if I am supposed to add `a` and `b` or to do the code again with the new values.

What are the values for `mystery(2, 25)` and `mystery(3, 11)` respectively?

```
public static int mystery(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return 0;
    if (b % 2 == 0) return mystery(a+a, b/2);
    return mystery(a+a, b/2) + a;
}
```

Answer to choose from:

```
33554432, 177147
525, 1331
50, 33
75, 44
```

Comment: Get a pencil and paper and write out the steps.  You might understand recursion when you're done.

Comment: Debug it in your IDE. So you can step through your code and watch the variables changing.

Comment: Have you left this question?

Comment: No still dont understand everything hehe

Comment: I wrote everything down on a paper and I finally understand! Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

I create an image trying to illustrate the answer...

-About the +2 you have to add after the return of the next call back...

Note: If you pass a float value to int parameter as 12.5 the parameter will get only the integer part: 12

If it is ok, please check as correctly! ;)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the picture. I do understand all the steps and why the code continues until b=0. But i dont understand why the answer is 50 and 33. Is it because 2*25 is 50 and 3*11=33 ?

Comment: I wrote everything down on a paper and I finally understand! Thank you for all the help and the image. It help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate each call to mystery until b is 0 and the recursive call chain terminates. You then add the final 0 result with the intermediate a (the +a) in the code.

Comment: It's not an answer.